# Show that the group is isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $H$ $\bigcap$ $K$ = {$e$}, prove that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/H$ $\bigoplus$ $G/K$.

What I have so far:

Let $\phi$: $G$ $\mapsto$ $G/H$ $\bigoplus$ $G/K$ such that $\phi$($a$)=($aH$, $aK$). Then for every $a,b$ $\in$ $G$. We have

$\phi$$(a)$$\phi$$(b)$

=($aH$, $aK$)($bH$, $bK$)

=($abH$, $abK$)

=$\phi$($ab$).

So $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Now we will show that $\phi$ is one-to-one. Suppose that $\phi$($a$)=$\phi$($b$). Then $aH$=$bH$ and $aK$=$bK$.

Comment: From your equations $b^{-1}a \in H$ and $b^{-1}a \in K$ so...?

Comment: Oh, okay. Well I guess that was easy.